# plotly: Can’t get polar scatter working in a subplot

Tags: plotly

I am having trouble putting a histogram and polar scatter plot in two subplots. Here's my code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{}, {}]])

trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=np.random.uniform(1,6,size=62),
)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)


trace2 = go.Scatter(
    r = np.random.uniform(1,6,size=62),
    t = np.random.uniform(30,5,size=62),
    mode='markers',
)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='temp.html')
```

This only renders the histogram correctly - and doesn't plot anything for the polar scatter plot. If I comment out `fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)`, I am able to get the polar scatter plot. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had a look at it, and I am thinking plotly simply cannot do polar plots in a subplot.  You code looks good and it runs fine if I substitute `x` for `r` and `y` for `t`. Will file it as an issue.

Comment: Yeah I got a similar answer at plotly's forums https://community.plot.ly/t/cant-get-polar-scatter-working-in-a-subplot/4261. Thanks for helping out though :) I hope it can be fixed soon.